# NSMutableArray and batchNode problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making a little game, here is some example code of whats going on:

```
-(id) init
{
       self.arrowProjectileArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
       self.batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"arrow.png"]];
       [self addChild:_batchNode z:2];
        for (CCSprite *projectile in _arrowProjectileArray) {
        [_batchNode removeChild:projectile cleanup:YES];
        }
        [_arrowProjectileArray removeAllObjects];
        self.nextProjectile = nil; 
        }
    }

-(void) callEveryFrame:(ccTime)dt{
    for (int i = 0; i < [_arrowProjectileArray count];i++) {
           CCSprite *cursprite = [_arrowProjectileArray objectAtIndex:i];
           if (cursprite.tag == 1) {
           float x = theSpot.x+10;
           float y = theSpot.y+10;
           cursprite.position = ccp(x, y);
           }
        }

    - (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
    [_batchNode addChild:_nextProjectile z:1 tag:1];
        [_arrowProjectileArray addObject: _nextProjectile];
        [self spriteMoveFinished];
    }
    -(void) dealloc
    {
        self.arrowProjectileArray = nil;
        self.nextProjectile = nil;
        [super dealloc];
    }
```

The only code that I included was code that is relevant to the arrow's projection.
The arrow shoots fine, the problem is every time I shoot the stupid thing, I think it shoots a new arrow, but puts multiple arrows onto of that 1 arrow and makes it look like a fat ugly  arrow pixel thing. What am I doing wrong? I'm not too familiar with NSMutableArray, but I'm currently stuck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my own problem by doing a little bit of research, I also got rid of the batch node.

Answer (score -1):

In init method, you create a new NSMutableArray instance and assign it to self.arrowProjectileArray, then you traverse the arrowProjectileArray in the following lines using a for loop. If addChild: method does not add anything to arrowProjectileArray, then your code has a logic mistake, because what you do by traversing arrowProjectileArray is traversing an empty array, which means you do nothing in that code.

You should double-check what you intend to do and what your code is doing actually.

Comment: I don't think you read all the code... the arrows ARE added into the array, they do shoot out. It's just its re-using the same arrows and doing something strange. Look in touchesBegan